# clvm package in repo

Tags: 20.04, lvm

Want to install **clvm** on my ubuntu 20.04 but the [last release of **clvm** package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=clvm&searchon=names) is for 18.04 . So, maybe someone know, it will be for 20.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be packaging issue, I reported [bug 1879450 about this](https://pad.lv/1879450).

Also what is interesting the [`WHATS_NEW` file](https://salsa.debian.org/lvm-team/lvm2/-/blob/master/WHATS_NEW) has the following lines:

> ```
> Version 2.03.00 - 10th October 2018
> ===================================
> ...
>   Remove clvmd
> ```

So the answer is **never**.
But you can still use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS to use `clvmd` and other [executables and services](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/clvm/filelist).

Comment: Hi @n0rbert ! Thank you so much 4 ur bug report! I hope it will be on repos soon, cuz i can't use 18.04 :'(

Comment: Looks like CLVM was deprecated upstream years ago, then removed from Debian, then removed from Ubuntu after 19.04. Consider migrating to lvm2-lockd